# APC PDU has wrong idea of its outlets

Tags: power-distribution-unit, apc

I have a APC rack PDU here. It should be AP7953, although that doesn't show in the telnet interface:

```
About System

Model Number      :
Serial Number     :
NMC Serial Number :
Manufacture Date  : ~
Hardware Revision :
MAC Address       : 72 61 73 65 00 00
Flash Type        : AMD A29DL322DB
```

This is a unit with 24 outlets, but the telnet interface only shows 8. Also, switching on all outlets ("Master control") doesn't actually switch on anything.

Both the OS and the RPDU application on the PDU have been upgraded to 3.9.2.

What can I do to regain control of the PDU outlets?

Answer (score 2):

Open a case with APC. On different equipment I would say that the device has lost connection to its backplane.